# C - Having trouble with the input/output of my structure in by using 2 functions

Tags: c, function, input, output, structure

Ok so my objective is to make a structure and give it some values through an input function and output them through an output function, for some reason its 
output is some scrambled symbols : -1    ░ùI&@0.000000

Any help?

P.S just to note, when I had  my input (scanf statements) and output( printf statements) in the function scan_element, it worked just fine. but when I divided it between two functions, it posted the scrambled symbols above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

struct element_t  {
        int number;
        char name[20];
        char symbol[3];
        char type[20];
        float atomic_weight;
        char shells[6];
    };

void scan_element(struct element_t pl);
void print_element(struct element_t pl);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    struct element_t pl;
    scan_element(pl);
    print_element(pl);
    return 0;
}

void scan_element(struct element_t pl)
{
    printf("number:");
    scanf("%d",&pl.number);

    printf("name:");
    scanf("%s",&pl.name);

    printf("symbol:");
    scanf("%s",&pl.symbol);

    printf("class:");
    scanf("%s",&pl.type);

    printf("atomic weight:");
    scanf("%f",&pl.atomic_weight);

    printf("shells use underscore for spaces :");
    scanf("%s",&pl.shells);
}

void print_element(struct element_t pl)
{
    printf("%d",pl.number);
    printf("%s",pl.name);
    printf("%s",pl.symbol);
    printf("%s",pl.type);
    printf("%f",pl.atomic_weight);
    printf("%s",pl.shells);
}
```

Comment: Lookup passing arguments by *address* in your materials. Your `scan_element` doesn't change the `p1` in main; it's only changing a local variable. This is an incredibly common question for people just learning C, but unfortunately the hunt for a duplicate is non-trivial, as the questions are so divergent in content it's difficult to pin one down. Sorry about that.

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to the "pl" variable defined in main in your two functions scan_element and print-element. So redefine the functions like scan_element(struct element_t * pl) and access to the field like pl->name.

Comment: @WeatherVane no prob,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are passing structure variable to `scan_element()`. When you pass by value, it actually creates a copy of `pl` in main and gives to `scan_element()`. The parameters you read in that function will be written to the copied structure variable. So `pl` in `main()` remain uninitialized.

**Solution**
You need to pass the address of the `pl` variable in main to `scan_element()`. You have to modify `scan_element()` to accept the address as below.

```
void scan_element(struct element_t *pl)
{
    printf("number: ");
    scanf("%d", &pl->number);

    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%s", pl->name); //Array name itself points to array. So you don't have to write '&'.

    printf("symbol: ");
    scanf("%s", pl->symbol);

    printf("class: ");
    scanf("%s", pl->type);

    printf("atomic weight: ");
    scanf("%f", &pl->atomic_weight);

    printf("shells use underscore for spaces: ");
    scanf("%s", pl->shells);
}
```

And modify the main() to pass address.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    struct element_t pl;

    scan_element(&pl);
    print_element(pl);

    return 0;
}
```

No changes required in `print_element()`.

Comment: Although changing print_element to use a pointer is not *required*, I would still think it would be more idiomatic to do so. It makes the whole program more consistent and also avoids copying the struct before printing it, which can be a bit more efficient.

Comment: @Ventus I agree with hugomg. You have to make similar change for print_element(). I hope you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to dereference a pointer where you shouldn't be when printing out your strings in `scan_element()`. Additionally, `scan_element()` is being passed a structure variable instead of a pointer reference to that variable. When you pass by value, C creates a copy of the structure (in this case, `pl`) so you're editing the new structure instead of the original one which you want to be editing.

This **solution** should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

 struct element_t
{
    int number;
    char name[20];
    char symbol[3];
    char type[20];
    float atomic_weight;
    char shells[6];
};

void scan_element(struct element_t *pl); // now accepts a pointer (*)
void print_element(struct element_t pl);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    struct element_t pl;

    scan_element(&pl); // derefrence
    print_element(pl);

    return 0;
}

void scan_element(struct element_t *pl) // now accepts a pointer (*)
{
    printf("number: ");
    scanf("%d", &pl.number);

    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%s", pl.name); // removed dereference here

    printf("symbol: ");
    scanf("%s", pl.symbol); // removed dereference here

    printf("class: ");
    scanf("%s", pl.type); // removed dereference here

    printf("atomic weight: ");
    scanf("%f", &pl.atomic_weight);

    printf("shells use underscore for spaces: ");
    scanf("%s", pl.shells); // removed dereference here
}

void print_element(struct element_t pl)
{
    printf("%d", pl.number);
    printf("%s", pl.name);
    printf("%s", pl.symbol);
    printf("%s", pl.type);
    printf("%f", pl.atomic_weight);
    printf("%s", pl.shells);
}
```

Comment: This code will not work as you are reading to local structure variable in  scan_element().

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the feedback! I missed that by looking over the code too quickly. I updated the answer.

Comment: One more thing you missed! Function prototype at the beginning!

Comment: Thank you again! I should refrain from doing this on 3 hours of sleep. xD

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer by [@CodyPatterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231964/cody-patterson), there is another problem. The `scan_element()` function  is accepting a structure by value. Its signature is

`void scan_element(struct element_t pl)`

This means that when the function is called and you pass a parameter, say an object `x`, a *copy of the object* is created and passed to the function. Then, the function accepts the value and stores them in the copy. The copy is local to the function, so when the function returns, it is destroyed, and all the data gathered is lost. The original object `x` *remains unchanged*. The result when printing could be garbage values.

To correct this, pass the object to the function by reference. By doing so, the original object is worked upon in the function, which is what is desired here. The function signature should be

`void scan_element(struct element_t &pl)`